# How to get the identity of a person invoking a transaction inside a transaction in Hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to save the identity of the user invoking a transaction in hyperledger composer. is there a way of getting the user identity inside a transaction without passsing it as a transaction parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your users are managed. Typically an organization has a couple of fabric users that invoke transactions on the blockchain. This user can be determined by the ledger. However if you authenticate users at the application level then invoke with the same fabric client there is no way of drilling down to know which user from within an organization invoked the transaction without passing the user as part of the transaction

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question, Hyperledger composer has a global method `getCurrentParticipant` that can be called inside the transaction to get the participant invoking the transaction.  Also it has `getCurrentIdentity` which can be used to get the identity of the current participant. [for more information](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/runtime-api#getcurrentparticipant)